# Chaincode (smart contract) interactions within and across channels in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, smartcontracts

Consider the Organization-Peer setup in a Hyperledger Fabric network as shown in the image.

[image]

Org 1 has two peers, Org 2 has one peer - all of which exist inside the same channel - X. Org 3 has one peer which exist outside in a different channel.

The peers have distinct chaincodes(c1, c2, c3 & c4) installed in each of them with the functions as explained.

```
write() - put a key-value pair into the ledger  
update() - update a value for an existing key  
read() - query an existing key-value pair
```

Now on to few questions.

1. Can c3 invoke c2 to update a key's value (as c3 do not have `update()`function)?
2. Can c4 invoke c2 to update a key's value (as c4 do not have `update()`function)?
3. Can `c3.read()` query the data created by `c1.write()` ?
      [This link](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/chaincode.html#what-is-chaincode) on chaincode tutorial says "State created by a chaincode is scoped exclusively to that chaincode and can’t be accessed directly by another chaincode". Does this apply for peers in the same channel too? As per my understanding blockchain ledger data is accessible to all participating peers.
4. Can `c4.read()` query the data created by `c1.write()` ?
5. Can `c2.update()` update the data created by `c1.write()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Peers can only execute chaincode that they have installed and have access to (local). You can have multiple chaincode for a given peer, but you can't have peers executing chaincode of other peers.

From `ChaincodeStub.invokeChaincode(chaincodeName, args, channel)` documentation at https://fabric-shim.github.io/ChaincodeStub.html#invokeChaincode__anchor:

> Locally calls the specified chaincode invoke() using the same transaction context; that is, chaincode calling chaincode doesn't create a new transaction message.

You should be able to install each chaincode for all peers and use the `ChaincodeStub.invokeChaincode` method along with the `ClientIdentity` class (https://fabric-shim.github.io/ClientIdentity.html) to handle with access control.